# Import a python module in multiple AWS Lambdas

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a couple of AWS Lambda functions. All of those functions use some common helper functions. I have placed these helper functions in a separate file called `helper_functions.py`. I want to import this module in all of my AWS Lambda functions. I am unable to find a place to store this module (`helper_functions.py`), so when I make a change in this module I don't have to change anything in my Lambda functions.

Some of the options I thought of are:

1. Uploading the module on AWS S3 and then loading it in each Lambda
   function in the start from S3 and using the functions. (if possible)
2. Writing some script (which I haven't figured out yet) that packages the module along with the Lambda
   functions' Python file in a zip and uploads it on AWS Lambda

Please suggest a better solution to manage the module and import it in a much more efficient way.

Comment: Lambda package has a size limit. You should include all the modules that fits in that size inside the zip package. Rest of the modules you can store in s3 and import from there.

Comment: If I include the module in all the Lambda packages and then I want to change something in the module, I will have to update all the Lambda packages, right?

Comment: including modules from zip packages will be more efficient I guess. You can write a small script to update the modules in all the packages. Check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

Comment: I don't quit understand the problem. If you have that single module and can import it from s3, changing it means you won't have to change anything in your scripts anyway. If there's a technical problem I'm missing here, you could always download that module in runtime and `sys.path.append` its path to use it. Not amazing, but will work.

Comment: Look at the parts about pip (and virtualenvs) here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for a long time. Here's my solution (there might be a better way):

setup your helper function in your file system like this:

`pathToSomewhere/my_helper/helper_functions.py
pathToSomewhere/my_helper/__init__.py
pathToSomewhere/setup.py`

Where `__init__.py` is:

```
from .helper_functions import *
```

and `setup.py` is

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_helper',
      version='0.10000',
      description='My helper functions',
      url='http://github.com/user/example',
      license='Proprietary',
      author='Null',
      author_email='null@example.com',
      packages=['my_helper'],
      install_requires=['boto3'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Now let's package up `my_helper`. From `pathToSomewhere/` run:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

I'm assuming you already know how to create and upload a virtual environment for running your lambda function. If not, let me know.

Now let's install `my_helper` into the virtual env of your lambda function. Let's assume your virtual environment is called `worker_env`

```
./worker-env/bin/pip install file://pathToSomewhere/my_helper
```

Now zip up `worker-env` and your actual lambda script and upload that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But currently I am one step ahead doing continuous delivery using AWS Codepipeline which is really cool and is easy to package and deploy any of your serverless application. Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html) out to get started.

Comment: I have a similar issue, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730389/shared-python-libraries-between-multiple-apis-on-aws?noredirect=1#comment86477048_49730389). However, with your solution, if I change `helper_functions.py` I'll have to re-zip all my AWS functions are re-upload them. Can the `helper_functions.py` be stored somewhere (e.g. `S3` maybe) and be imported by all my AWS Lambdas so that if I change it, I don't have to re-zip everything.